# How to change the selector every time when the loop is executed?

Tags: robotframework

In my below script, I want to change the value of the variable `${drop_down_items}` every time when the loop is executed.

```
div.col:nth-child(**2**) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > combo-box:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div
```

In the above locator I want to increment the nth-child value from 2 to 3, 3 to 4 and so on every time when the loop is executed.

```
*** Variables ***
${combo_boxes}      css=div.col > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > combo-box:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)
${drop_down_items}  css=div.col:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > combo-box:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div
*** Keywords ***
Loop
  @{combo_boxes}=  Get WebElements  ${combo_boxes}
  :FOR    ${each}     IN      @{combo_boxes}
  \  Click Element  ${each}
  \  Loop A
  \  Sleep  0.5s
  \  Click Element  ${each}

Loop A
  @{get_role_list}=  Get WebElements  css=div.col:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > combo-box:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div
  :FOR    ${each}     IN      @{get_role_list}
  \    Sleep  0.5s
  \    Click Element  ${each}
  \    Sleep  0.5s
  \    Run Keyword If  '${each}'!='EXIT'  Click Element  ${combo_boxes}
```

Comment: Is this the HTML code of a public site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Loop
  @{combo_boxes}=  Get WebElements  ${combo_boxes}
  ${INTEGER} =    Set Variable  2
  Set Suite Variable  ${INTEGER_A}  ${INTEGER}
  :FOR    ${each}     IN      @{combo_boxes}
  \  Click Element  ${each}
  \  ${roles_list}=  Set Variable    css=.list > div:nth-child(${INTEGER_A}) > 
   div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > combo-box:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div
   \  Loop A  ${roles_list}  ${each}
   \  ${INTEGER_A}=  Evaluate    ${INTEGER_A} + 1
   \  Sleep  0.5s
   \  Click Element  ${each}


Loop A
  [Arguments]  ${roles_list}  ${combo}
  @{get_role_list}=  Get WebElements  ${roles_list}
  :FOR    ${each}     IN      @{get_role_list}
  \    Click Element "${each}"
  \    Run Keyword If  '${each}'!='EXIT'  Click Element  ${combo}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add another loop layer. In the Robot Framework Guide there is a section on the different looping functionality that Robot Framework offers. In particular have a loop at the [For-in-range section](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#for-in-range-loop). This is an example that should help with your problem.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Only upper limit
    [Documentation]    Loops over values from 0 to 9
    :FOR    ${index}    IN RANGE    10
    \    Log    ${index}
```